# get ansible facts dynamically in playbook

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-facts

I have ansible facts like below,

```
 "facter_partitions": {
            "/dev/loop0": {
                "backing_file": "/a",
                "size": "10.92 GiB",
                "size_bytes": 3080000000
            },
            "/dev/loop1": {
                "backing_file": "/b",
                "size": "11.92 GiB",
                "size_bytes": 1080000000
            },
            "/dev/loop10": {
                "backing_file": "/c",
                "size": "12.02 GiB",
                "size_bytes": 2064000000
            }
            },
```

How can we get the key and value pairs dynamically in playbook. may be using for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dictionary. You have to convert it to a list using [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-dictionary), then you can access the key-value pairs for each item as,

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
     "facter_partitions": {
            "/dev/loop0": {
                "backing_file": "/a",
                "size": "10.92 GiB",
                "size_bytes": 3080000000
            },
            "/dev/loop1": {
                "backing_file": "/b",
                "size": "11.92 GiB",
                "size_bytes": 1080000000
            },
            "/dev/loop10": {
                "backing_file": "/c",
                "size": "12.02 GiB",
                "size_bytes": 2064000000
            }
       }
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ item.key }} -  {{ item.value.backing_file }}"
      loop: "{{ facter_partitions | dict2items }}"
```

This will produce an output like,

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={'key': u'/dev/loop10', 'value': {u'size_bytes': 2064000000, u'backing_file': u'/c', u'size': u'12.02 GiB'}}) => {
    "msg": "/dev/loop10 -  /c"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={'key': u'/dev/loop1', 'value': {u'size_bytes': 1080000000, u'backing_file': u'/b', u'size': u'11.92 GiB'}}) => {
    "msg": "/dev/loop1 -  /b"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={'key': u'/dev/loop0', 'value': {u'size_bytes': 3080000000, u'backing_file': u'/a', u'size': u'10.92 GiB'}}) => {
    "msg": "/dev/loop0 -  /a"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but if i try below playbook to get the value backing_file, it's failing 

- debug: msg: "{{ item.key }} - {{ item.value.backing_file }}"
  loop: "{{ facter_partitions | dict2items }}"


The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'backing_file

Comment: Use `with_dict: "{{ facter_partitions }}"` instead of `loop` and try. Both are identical. Not sure why it is not picking the nested key

Comment: Used with_dict. It's failing with same error for **value.backing_file**,  ** {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'backing_file**. where as it's working for **value.size**

Comment: thanks @franklinsijo, the issue was resolved. Actually, backing_file is missing in other occurrences. `when: item.value.backing_file is defined` statement resolved the issue

Comment: Ah okay, Since the sample dict in the question did not miss any key, I did not think of adding a conditional.